# Can't get all of the data from given bin file in C

Tags: c, file

I have a C task which is asking for reading given bin file, sorting students grade on a new txt file and getting statistics of these on a new txt file. I'm writing my code right now didn't came sorting on new file part but I am having a problem while reading student struct.Testing with names I'm getting few names after somepoint it just stops. I don't know what I am doing wrong and how can i fix this. I tried with 2 bin files given, results are different but in both it stops  somewhere(different for both file) before coming end.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct student
{ //Structure for the records in the file
char Name[30];
char Surname[30];
char address[50];
unsigned long long No;
unsigned int st_class;
unsigned int Section;
int grade;
} ;
typedef struct student Students;
struct stats{ //Structure for number of students, maximum, minimum and average
int no; //number of students
int max; //maximum
int min; //minimum
double avg; //average
};
typedef struct stats Statistics;
int read_student_database(char *, Students []);
void count_students_in_sections(Students [], int, Statistics []);
double calculate_statistics(Students [], int, Statistics []);
void display_and_save_statistics(char *,Statistics [], int, double);
void sort_and_save_data(char *, Students [], int);

char name[100]={'\0'};

Students student[200];
Statistics satats[250];

int main()
{
    printf("Enter your name_surname (in capital letters):");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    read_student_database(name,student);
}

int read_student_database(char *x,Students student[])
{
    char address[65]={'\0'};
    sprintf(address, "%s.bin",x);
    printf("%s\n",address);
    FILE *fptr;
        if((fptr=fopen(address,"r"))==NULL)
        printf("File could not be opened.\n");
        else
        {       
            int y=0,z=0,a=0;
            for(y=1;y<300;y++)
            {
                fread(&student[y], sizeof(struct student), 1, fptr);
                if(student[y].Name!=NULL)
                {
                printf("%s\t",student[y].Name);
                a++;
                }
            }
            printf("%d",a);
            printf("%d",y);
        }
}
```

Here what result looks like 
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxlvW.png)

And here what bin file looks like in notepad
[bin file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPrbA.png)

*and sorry for english mistakes if I made some*

Comment: student has 200 elements but you are looping to the 300th element.

Comment: Are there exactly 299 records in the file?  You should check if fread is returning sizeof(struct student) each time.  Right now if the read fails you will print garbage.

Comment: There is 100ish record in file (we only know it's less than 200). I changed 300 to 200 it doesn't make any difference. Task is also asking for it we have to find how many record is there.

Comment: Looking at a binary file in Notepad is meaningless. There are two options to how the file was created and how you need to read it. (1) the data was serialized and written to the file -- in that case you will need to know how it was serialized to read it back in, or (2) the structs themselves were dumped to the file creating a non-portable data file that likely will only be useful using the same compiler to read the structs back in due to the differences in padding. You are likely looking at (2). So loop `int n = 0; while (n < 200 & fread (&student[n], sizeof *student, 1, fptr) == 1) n++;`

Comment: It would be helpful if you post a link to the binary file so the fomat can be confirmed in a hexdump program, but I suspect the array of structures was simply written to the file. If you know the number written, you can read them all in a single `fread` call replacing `1` above (the *nmemb* paramter)  with the number of struct to read.